# Data acquisition package/toolbox in Julia or Python

Tags: python, julia

Are there any toolbox or package in Julia which is similar to the data acquisition toolbox of Matlab? In Python I encountered [Pyserial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/). Are there more?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `pySerial` directly from Julia via the `PyCall.jl` package.

To make life easier `pySerial` is easily available as `SerialPorts.jl` Julia package, so the setup should be straight forward. Please note that this package is not yet translated to Julia 1.0. However it installs (with warnings) under Julia 0.7.

Note that `pySerial` is using Java Communications API (JavaComm) so another option is to download JavaComm from Oracle and use it via `JavaCall.jl` API. This is easy if you have some basic knowledge of Java (requires reading and understanding Java docs).

From Julia you can also call directly C libraries. One such library is `libserialport`. It has been already repackaged for Julia as `LibSerialPort.jl`.